# How to connect to my ubuntu VNC server from outside my network

Tags: networking, server, vnc, remote-access

How can I connect to my ubuntu pc running vncserver from outside my network?

I can access it from inside my home network using 192.168.1.123:3389 (the address of the pc and the port I have opened usign xrdp).

I have also forwarded the port on my routers settings (and pointed it at 192.169.1.123 and port 3389), so that I should be able to access it. I used https://canyouseeme.org/ and it says that the port is open.

But when I try to connect using my ip xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:3389 it wont work and either times out or just cancels.

What should I do?

Comment: what happens if you type the command `ping xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:3389` ?

Comment: Do I do this on my Ubuntu pc or the computer I am trying to connecting from?

Comment: When I try from my phone it says: unknown host

Comment: Yep, I have full access to the web from the Ubuntu pc and can access it from inside my network from my laptop

Comment: Thanks, I will try following this guide

Comment: Since you can use VNC successfully within your home network, you seem to have conclusively demonstrated that your Ubuntu system is properly working. Don't change any settings on your Ubuntu system. Your problem seems to be with either with your router settings or your ISP, neither of which we can really help much with, since those are not about Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you using VNC or RDP? The port and your mention of xrdp points to rdp, while you have clearly tagged it vnc, and also mention this.